# Adding up all the rows in a particular column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables: one called Projects, and another called Documents (projects has many documents, documents belong to projects).

The Projects table has a "limit" integer column wherein the user can specify the number of Documents they need.

I want to add up all of the limits and get a single value. So for example, if project A has a limit of 5, project B has a limit of 10, and project C has a limit of 8, I want to be able to display "23".

What's the proper Ruby command for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base` exposes the SQL `SUM` function as the sum method, so

```
Project.sum(:limit)
```

should do the trick. This is aware of scopes and so on, so you could do

```
Project.where(:active => true).sum(:limit)
```

to calculate the sum only for rows where `active` was true or

```
person.projects.sum(:limit)
```

to sum the limits of the projects associated with a person (assuming person `has_many` or habtm projects)

`MIN`, `MAX` and `AVERAGE` are exposed in similar ways.